# MySQL Database Field with Perl Variables

Tags: mysql, perl, variables

I am using Perl DBI to access some MySQL database fields. I have a field that contains text and some Perl variables. The Perl variables aren't being interpreted as variables. Is there a way to somehow mark the variables in the MySQL field so that they will be interpreted in Perl?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us an example?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to "markup" the contents of a MySQL column (field) to force Perl to evaluate the contents of a text string containing variable names.

This issue doesn't really have anything to do with MySQL.

This is covered in the Perl FAQ. [**How can I expand variables in text strings?**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3f)

As an example, a string that contains two Perl scalar variables in it.

```
 $string = 'Say hello to $foo and $bar';
```

(That string literal is in single quotes, so $foo and $bar aren't interpreted as variables, those are just characters in the literal string.)

But I want to expand `$foo` and `$bar` to their variable's values. Let's say I have these variables defined:

```
 my $foo = 'Fred';
 my $bar = 'Barney';
```

One way I can get the `$foo` and `$bar` in the text string replaced with the values of the variables is to use the substitution operator and a double `/e` flag.

The first `/e` evaluates `$1` on the replacement side and turns it into `$foo`.

The second `/e` starts with `$foo` and replaces it with the value of the variable `$foo`, so `$foo` gets replaced with `'Fred'`

```
 $string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; # 'Say hello to Fred and Barney'
```